# UBuntu 14.04 LTS - switching between nvidia and nouveau drivers - blacklist

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I found a similiar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585256/switching-between-nvidia-prop-and-nouveau-with-reboot). In my case a catalog `/etc/modprobe.d/` doesn't contain `blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf` but there is `nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` Can I use following command (when switching to nouveau) :  `sed -i "s/nouveau/nvidia/" /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` or I should create an another conf file which name contains blacklist string ? How does it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Blacklisting nouveau will not work, because they are contained in initrd. You would have to remove the module manually. I think the best way to switch between the drives is to use the tool Additional Drivers.